# Trying to align <h1> and <p> elements at left of my icon font

Tags: html, css

I have an icon font on the left and I want to put a `<h1>` and a `<p>` elements on the right side of my *lock* icon font.

I want the `<h1>` above and `<p>` below and I also  want the `<p>` at center.

But I want the `<h1>` and `<p>` align at center, but they are always aligning in the left.

I already tried with margin:0 auto; and text-align:center; but nothing works.

Somebody there see what Im doing wrong?

Im trying something like this:

[image]

**My jsfiddle with the problem:**

(I try to add my font-awesome.css to my fiddle but I guess it doesnt works)

http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/K3Y5W/1/

**My html:**

```
<div id="login">
    <div id="align_center">
    <h1>Reserved Area</h1>
    <p>Cookies and Creams</p>
    <span class="lock"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

**My css:**

```
#login{position:absolute; background:green; top:50%; left:50%; height:320px; width:300px; margin-top:-160px; margin-left:-150px;}
#login p {float:left; color:#000; font-family:'verdana'; font-size:18px; text-align:center;}
#login h1 {float:left; color:#000;font-family:'verdana'; font-size:35px;}
#login span>i{color:#fff; font-size:5em;}
#align_center {margin:0 auto; text-align:center;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are floating the elements to the left:

```
#login p {float:left; color:#000; font-family:'verdana'; font-size:18px; text-align:center;}
#login h1 {float:left; color:#000;font-family:'verdana'; font-size:35px;}
```

Don't do that :)

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K3Y5W/7/)

---

So here's what I did.

#### 1. Remove the float from the login elements

Instead, apply the opposite, `float:right;` to the container element, `.align-center`.

#### 2. Force a width on the container

By default, `<div>'s` are 100% width, so you have to define it to fit in the width allowed, which is, in this case, 396px.

#### 3. Set a top margin

To align the `<h1>` and `<p>`, you need to set a top margin to push them down, in this case, I used CSS3's `calc()` function to get the exact margin to center it, which is (50% - 65px) / 2, or just (25% - 32px).

```
width: calc(25% - 32px);
```

Comment: Thanks man!! But now with my icon font my both elements are above the icon font lock and I want them more down, Im trying with margin-bottom and bottom 0 but without sucess

Comment: You can float the entire *container*, but not the elements themselves. If you want to move them down, set the margin-top, not the margin-bottom, or use `position:relative; top:15px;` (this will move them down 15px)

Comment: Are you looking more for [**something like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/K3Y5W/5/)?

Comment: Thanks, Im trying that but then all my login div is going down!

Comment: Yes..but then I want thay my <h1> and <p> goes down to be centering with the image!

Comment: Yes..its really that. Thank you, I´ll study to understand what you did! :)

Comment: @androidY You're welcome! I'll put the specifics in an edit to my answer.

Comment: Using `calc()` should be limited because many old browsers don't support it.

Comment: @KingKing [Only really old browsers don't support calc()](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Answer (score 2):

Floated elements are "srhink-wrapped," meaning that they'll get sized to their content. Next, you ask it to center the text within the element, which really does nothing---there's no extra space to center it in. Set a width on the `<h1>` and `<p>`.

Comment: Thanks..it works to center the text! But I still have the problem of putting my <p> and <h1> a bit down